# bitbake can't find file in do_compile stage

Tags: bitbake

Yacto/bitbake newbie here. Forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to build a simple hello world program in c using yacto/bitbake. And keep getting file not found error. Here is my recipe file.

```
DESCRIPTION = "A friendly program that prints Hello World!"
PRIORITY = "1"

SECTION = "examples"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

PV = "0.1"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}/${PN}-${PV}-${PR}"

do_compile() {
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
install -d ${D}${bindir}
install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

---

The files are located like this:
recipes-helloworld/helloworld/files/helloworld.c
recipes-helloworld/helloworld/helloworld_0.1.bb